# useReducer - how to grab and update previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have two problems when trying to update my state.
First of all, the first letter in the input is not being updated directly to the state - in the console.log I can see that the useReducer is first calling the initialState and then is dispatching the actions, so the registered input is one letter behind the actual user's input.

Could you please guide me and show me what would be the best way to update the state of my object? I think I should divide the dispatch on more keys, but I feel a little bit lost and don't really know how to dispatch it correctly.

PS of course I dispatched more actions - that work - so I hid some of them, hence the structure of initial state :)

**Calling useReducer in Inputs.ts**

```
const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

**Actions.ts**

```
export const SET_INPUT_STATE = 'SET_INPUT_STATE';
export const setInputState = (dispatch, payload) => dispatch({ type: SET_INPUT_STATE, payload });
```

**Store.ts**

```
import { SET_INPUT_STATE } from './actions';

export interface StateType {
  formState: Record<string, { value: string; isValid: boolean }>;
}

export const initialState: StateType = {
  inputState: {
    email: {
      value: '',
      isValid: false,
    },
    password: {
      value: '',
      isValid: false,
    },
    confirmedPassword: {
      value: '',
      isValid: false,
    },
    name: {
      value: '',
      isValid: false,
    },
  },
};

export const reducer = (state: StateType, action): StateType => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SET_FORM_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        inputState: { ...state.inputState, [payload.name]: { isValid: payload.isValid, value: payload.value } },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Where are you dispatching the action? A full exmaple with UI would help, since your state is so tied to the UI. Eg in a codesandbox

Comment: Initially, I was doing the logic inside of the function in the concerned file. So, basically it works, but is one typo behind + I wanted to move this logic to the reducer instead of keeping it in the function in the component.

setFormState(deploy, (state) => {
      console.log(state);
      return {
        ...state.formState,
        [name]: {
          value,
          isValid: !hasError,
        },
      };

Comment: okay, I figured out that part, but now when I'm using it over an input field, the store is one iteration behind the actual input... any idea why?
    const isAnyFieldInvalid = Object.values(registerStore.formState).some((val) => val.isValid === false);

this line breaks it, but have no idea why it causes it

Comment: Are you dispatching SET_INPUT_STATE? Your reducer is working on SET_FORM_STATE, so it won't work